# Opencart product_id changes

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I'm busy setting up an online store using Opencart 2.0.3.1. Everyday I get a new updated product file and I upload it with an **Import/Export** extension. Each product is loaded against a Auto incremental `product_id` and the `product_id` to product is not kept unique every time I load the new products.

**For example** if I load the file product P200 can be linked to `product_id` 1240. If if load again tomorrow that same product can be linked to `product_id` 1211. Now if a customer wrote a review on `product_id` 1240 it will be lost on the next update, because `product_id` 1240 will now link to another product.

Opencart does not record the review against the SKU but on the `product_id`. I would really appreciate it if someone can help here.

Comment: I had the same issue before, that's because the **Import/Export extension** deletes old products and re-inserts them again with new ids, unfortunately there is no solution for that (unless you hire some professional to write a customized data management tool for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the unique ids by storing your current ids with your identifier columns in a new table and creating a trigger to update the product_id with existing ones when inserting.

I'll show a simple example using only the product model as a unique field to match existing products.

```
Create Table map_products(id Int, model Varchar(64));

Insert Into map_products 
Select product_id, model From oc_product;

Delimiter $$
Create Trigger oc_product_insert Before Insert On oc_product
For Each Row
Begin
  Declare original_id Int;
  Select id Into original_id From map_products Where model = New.model;
  If (original_id IS NOT NULL) Then
    Set New.product_id = Select id From map_products Where model = New.model;
  Else
    // You either wouldn't have to do anything here or reseed your identity
    // column for new products depending on if the Import/Export extension
    // resets your identity seed. 

    // Also, you need to create new records in your map_products table too.
    Insert Into map_products Values (last_insert_id(), New.model);
  End If;
End$$
Delimiter ;
```

Sorry that I didn't test this code because I don't have a test environment for opencart but it should give a solid idea about what you can do. You'll need super user privilege in mysql to create the trigger if I'm not mistaken. Also please note that I used 'oc_' as it's the default prefix for opencart installation but you may have yours different.

Comment: Thanks Engin, I'm already doing that same thing in Excel before I upload the new data.

Comment: @NicoRoets well, actually that's what made me think of a solution using a trigger so you don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by forcing the products back to their original product_id in a excel workbook. then add any new products to the list with their new product_id's. Before I upload all product_id's is deleted and reloaded from the import. This is now an extra step but at least it's doing the job.